# Calculate most common time of day from spreadsheet values

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, data-mining

**Preliminary**

This question applies to any spreadsheet system. I would like help in breaking down the problem, as opposed to an answer to the problem. (Although the latter would be most useful.)

I understand Stack Overflow is good for specific programming problems, and I understand it may take me a few attempts to get my question right, so please help me clarify my question by providing suggestions and I will update it.

Like many data novices I have good experience with discreet data (e.g. how many enquiries last month), but I struggle to understand how to deal with continuous data (e.g. how to discover patterns, and where the criteria for a query are not yet known).

**The question**

I have a spreadsheet where each row represents a "website enquiry". There is a datetime column, and I'd like to discover patterns in this data, to answer questions like:

- what is the most common time of day to receive an enquiry
- what is the most common day of the week to receive an enquiry
- other useful information I can glean from the data, to allow me to target possible customers

This would be similar to the functions you often see in Social Media analytics, such as "best time to tweet".

I understand that calculating the most common day of the week is very simple, as days are discreet objects. So I don't need help with this!

I would like to avoid simply splitting up the day into four arbitrary time periods (e.g. breakfast, lunch, dinner, nighttime) and counting the number of rows that fall into these bounds. What if these time periods are not best to use to segment the data?

Is there another way, other than quantizing my data using arbitrary bounds?

Comment: This is where databases are infinitely more useful than spreadsheets

Comment: Visualise the data by using a pivot table? Group the date field(assuming its a dateTime) by hour. Pivot table are a very good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use clustering to find out what the most common times are. Basically, you compare the time separation of enquiries and cluster them just like discrete 1D set of numbers using, for example, the average linkage clustering criterion. As you reach a reasonably small number of clusters, you will start to see the most dominant times of day (and if you want to evaluate those, you can take the time values which are the weighted centres of the biggest clusters).